# Faces missing before Subdivision modifier and leaves small holes after

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

Im modelling a phone and so in order to create the speaker holes, I created a circle, applied an array modifier and then joined it with the main phone body. then I deleted the faces that the circles were sitting on and redid the topology by myself, working around the circles to create holes. then I extruded the circles inward to make holes. however after doing so the faces at the bottom of the extrusion/hole are not appearing unless I add a sub surf modifier, but thats not much of a problem since I intended to do so anyway but id like to know why this is happening. The problem arises when I add the sub surf and crank it up to 2 levels, a small hole/crack appears in the mesh when I do so. how do I fix this? (see images attached)

[image: Before sub surf]
[image: After sub surf]

Note: I tried recalculating normals but that didn't do much. I could fix the smaller hole at the top by bevelling the circle that I extruded to make the hole but I don't really like how that looks plus the other hole doesn't get fixed by this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that these vertices are not connected to anything:

[image]

There are other aspects of the mesh that don't have good topology yet, but you may be on the way to fixing those in the way you want to, depending on your plans for the model.

Comment: thank you, this is only my second time using blender so im making a lot of mistakes. I got those vertices by just extruding the vertices to their right and I realise thats probably what caused the problem. I instead added a loop cut to get those vertices and it works great! As for the other mistakes, im not sure what they are yet but I will try my best to make this model decent. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh also what about the disappearing faces? why is that happening? is it the same reason?

Comment: Hi, @pythonnewbie ! ..  There are no disappearing faces, that's the subdivision surface around the  illustrated hole 'cutting the corner'  on the open boundary. If you're making round insets  in separate panels to be welded in, you need the vertices on the boundaries of the panels to match the receiving hole, You may not need to make separate panels at all. Check out the shipped add-on _Loop Tools_ (> _Circle_ ) if you haven't already, and have a play in a separate space turning various connected 6-gons  and 8-gons into circles.

Comment: I dont understand what you said in the last bit, what do you mean by welding separate panels?

Comment: @pythonnewbie  .. that instead of insetting faces in the existing geometry, you make separate faces with the holes, and fit them in, merging the vertices on the perimeter.

Comment: oh! okay ill try that, thanks!